# Observable startWith isn't emitted in doOnNext

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a number of Observables that are used for network requests in my app. Since so much is the same, I apply an Observable transformation to them:

```
/**
 * Creates a transformer that applies the schedulers and error handling for all of the observables in this ViewModel.
 */
private fun applyTransformations(): Observable.Transformer<NetworkState, NetworkState> {
    return Observable.Transformer { observable ->
        observable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .onErrorReturn { NetworkState.Error(it) }
                .doOnNext { publishState(it) }
                .startWith(NetworkState.Loading())
    }
}
```

The goals I am trying to accomplish with the above:

- Apply consistent schedulers
- Handle any error by returning an instance of my sealed class.
- Handle any onNext by publishing the state returned by the observable.
- Start off by sending a Loading state.

This works mostly fine, but what I've noticed is that while I call `startWith` and a loading state, it is never actually handled by `doOnNext()`. In other words, `publishState()` is never called for my loading state.

Where I set up the observables, I don't bother to add a subscriber, because the `doOnNext()` above is all that I'll need:

```
val subscription = repository.getInstagramPhotos(count)
        .map { mapIGPhotoResponse(it) }
        .compose(applyTransformations())
        .subscribe()
```

If I were to supply a subscriber above, though, it would handle the loading state. It would also handle two `onNext()` calls - one for the subscriber supplied, and one for the `doOnNext` in the transform.

Is there a way to modify this `startWith` call to emit to whatever I've specified in `doOnNext`? I'm using RxJava 1.

Edit: Just to clarify some more, if I track what's emitted I expect to see two things. `Loading -> Success`. What I actually see is just `Success`. If I supply a subscriber to the observable I see `Loading -> Success -> Success`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`startWith` should be before `doOnNext`.

Rxjava methods, though they look like they use the builder pattern, actually don't. They return a new observable each time an operator is applied. In your case,  your doOnNext observable completes before your start with observable, so it's consumer isn't called with what you supply in startWith.

Ideally, you should go with:

```
observable
                .startWith(NetworkState.Loading()) 
                .doOnNext { publishState(it) }
                .onErrorReturn { NetworkState.Error(it) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Also, be careful with subscribing with no Consumer for `onEror` should it happen. Since you have nothing to consume the onError, RxJava will crash your app since it has nothing to notify for the error. Consider replacing the `doOnNext` with a Success Consumer in subscribe, and an empty Consumer for the error if you want to ignore it.

Also `doOnNext` is typically used for side effects, such as logging and the sort, they're more of a convenience than true functional operators.

Comment: If I have no consumer, won't it be handled with `onErrorReturn`? Also, I opted for `doOnNext()` because I have about 6 observables and I want to give the same subscriber to each one. I could define a subscriber at the class level, but I thought this would be good enough.

Comment: Also note: I had to move `onErrorReturn` before the `doOnNext` in order to have that be called as well. It works for now, but definitely some confusion now whether or not I implemented a best practice here.

Comment: @AdamMc331 onErrorReturn would only work within the stream. If an error occurred and OnErrorReturn is invoked, and doOnNext is, an exception in whatever doOnNext is would crash the app. Also if onErrorReturn is the fail safe, it should be before doOnNext.